# Как сделать чтобы загружаемые файлы через форму имели права 666?

Tags: php, linux

Делаю всё локально, сервер nginx

Есть файл, который загружаю:
**~/Videos/video.mp4**
У него права

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  8040040 гру 12 04:24 video.mp4
```

После загрузки через форму на сайте он попадает в каталог сайта:
**/var/www/local.site/media/videos/video.mp4**

И у него права меняются на

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 8040040 січ 17 02:14 video.mp4
```

Файл попадает в конечную директорию таким способом:

```
rename($path_to_source_file, $path_to_media_videos_file);
```

Как дать права доступа такие же как были у начального файла?

Comment: ..........`chmod` ?

Comment: Я везде ставил 777 права с рекурсией, но файл создаёт всё равно пользователем www-data и правами только чтение для групп и остальных

Comment: имел в виду, что на на php есть функция chmod,  её использовать

Comment: говорит что нет прав на использование через php

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону программы `umask`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Помогло следующее решение:

Вместо php5-fpm ваша версия.

1. Отредактировать файл */etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/php5-fpm.service* и добавить `UMask=0000` в секцию [Service].
2. Выполнить команду `systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Выполнить команду `systemctl restart php5-fpm.service`

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Не забудьте пометить свой ответ как правильный (нажать на галочку слева от текста) :)